# Modernizr load and cssanimations

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I have a slideshow which works fine when the code is added directly to the head, but does not work in the Modernizr load function.

I want the same page to load the required code files depending on the browser. I have tried using both Modernizr cssanimations and !Modernizr cssanimations to no avail.

Here is the code as it stands with annotations. Please help - Gordon.

```
css3 animations works in Safari
<!--link href="_css3/css3_SLIDEglobal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="_css3/css3_QUERYdisclose.js"></script-->



jQuery works in old Firefox and Opera
<!--link href="_jQ/jQ_SLIDEglobal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="_jQ/jQ_QUERYanimateDisclose.js"></script-->


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="modernizr-latest.js"></script>
```

Modernizr load with does not, ie !Modernizr, as recommended in the Q&A:

```
<script>
        Modernizr.load({
        test :        !Modernizr.cssanimations,
        yep :        ['_jQ/jQ_SLIDEglobal.css', '_jQ/jQ_QUERYanimateDisclose.js' ],
        nope  :      ['_css3/_css3_SLIDEglobal.css', '_css3/css3_QUERYdisclose.js']
                       });
        </script>
```

Modernizr load with does as seen on other sites:

```
<script>
        Modernizr.load({
        test :      Modernizr.cssanimations,
        yep  :      ['_css3/_css3_SLIDEglobal.css', '_css3/css3_QUERYdisclose.js'],
        nope :      ['_jQ/jQ_SLIDEglobal.css', '_jQ/jQ_QUERYanimateDisclose.js' ],
                       });
        </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have cleaned up the incorrect /_css3_ in file path of the yep statement and it still does not work. I also moved the css and jQuery files into the same folder to no avail. Here is some clean code:

Comment: (Apple K would not load code for some reason ) Does the fact that I am using MAMP as a localhost have any impact on Modernizr?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant extra li lurking in code. Once fixed, Modernizr.load works as expected. Interestingly the pages worked even with the li when only one set of style sheets was loaded.